# Firebase crashlytics for multiple build environment for iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

[image]

1 As above pic we created two project in our firebase account for iOS, one is pointing to production environment i.e. **ProductionApp** 
  and it’s Bundle id is **com.Production.ios**

2 Second **Test App** is point to our rest of the environment i.e. development, qa, staging. Their Bundle id are below

Development Bundle id   **com.Production.ios-Dev**

QA Bundle Id            **com.Production.ios-QA**

Staging Bundle Id       **com.Production.ios-Stag**

3 as per firebase suggestion "${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run" added in all environment

4 as you see the below pic crash is generated in production environment

[image]

[image]

5 Now i set my environment as development and manually generating the error but that error crash goes to production environment not in
Development environment likewise same for QA and Staging.

6 So how to achieve the crash in our development, QA, & Staging environment.

7 Please provide me some steps or video

Comment: It is related with `bundleId`

Comment: check your bundle id while you are testing build.

Comment: hi already created multiple target it work's fine but in firebase it will not work

Comment: any one have any solution for above please help me thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This article by Tyler Milner explains how to setup Crashlytics for iOS for multiple environments (staging and release).

https://medium.com/rocket-fuel/using-multiple-firebase-environments-in-ios-12b204cfa6c0

In summary, 2 different GoogleService-Info.plist is created in Firebase console, 1 for staging and 1 for release. Then, a custom script will attach the respective plist to the app when it is built.

Answer (score 0):

Got solution for google it will work fine now. Below answer from Google i just forward it for answer.
Hi Jaysingh,

Thanks for reaching out, and sorry for the delay. This behavior should now work as you expect it due to some recent work by our engineering team. I checked the 
 Test App bundle IDs and they are all activated except for the QA app. Can you double check that it is active in Firebase Crashlytics and let me know?